# bash: move a file from an unknown subdirectory (wildcard?)

Tags: bash, mv

Suppose there is a directory with many sub-directories `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`...
In one (and only one!) of these directories is a file called `x.txt` (but I don't know in which of the directories).

I wanted to move that file to an alternative directory using:

```
mv */x.txt {target_dir}
```

However this doesn't work: `No such file or directory`

As a solution I ended up looping over all sub-directories and checking if the file is there with `[ -f ]`, and moving the file once located.

However, I was wondering if there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name x.txt -exec mv {} target_dir \;
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned there are thousands of directories and thousands of files. I know the name of the file `x.txt` (and it's a unique name so I know that such file is in only in one directory). I will try this to see if your solution is faster.

Comment: @econ : You may replace the `.` with the base directory.

Comment: I think it's good to have a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/341232/faster-alternatives-to-find-and-locate)

Answer (score 1):

From the **bash** manpage:

```
globstar
        If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match
        all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the
        pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.
```

You could try enabling the 'globstar' option, and using

```
shopt -s globstar
echo **/x.txt
```

If the echo finds the file, so will the equivalent

```
mv **/x.txt {target_dir}
```

Note: **globstar** is a bash only option (added in bash 4.0)  If you use an older release (such as the bash 3 which is standard on the MAC) this will not work.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I'm using the default bash on OSX (3.2), but this is one extra reason to upgrade to 4.0. So I think that I will move to bash 4 over the summer.